# como solucionar? diagonal se sale del viewport usando css

Tags: css, viewport

dejo el siguiente código tal vez alguien me pudiera dar unas pistas para solucionar: la imagen muestra el error.

```css
 h1{margin:0}
 
 .div-cut.top {
  top: 0;
  border-top: 250px solid #fff;
  border-right: 100vw solid red;
}
 .div-cut {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
 }

 .absolut{position:absolute;}
 .fix{position:fixed}
 
 .EstilosParaFondo{
  z-index:10; 
  top:0; top:0; left:0; right:0; 
  margin:auto;  
  background-image:url('images/imagenOK.jpg'); 
  background-size:cover; 
  background-repeat:no-repeat; 
  height: 450px; 
 }
```

```html
  <div style="background:white; height:80vh; width:100%">
 <h1>Hello, world 1</h1>
  </div> 
  
  <div id="div2" style="position:relative; background-color:#FF4D4D;">
  
 <div id="triangle" class=" div-cut top">jofret</div>
 
 <div>

   <div style="height:100vh">
    <h1>Hello, world 2</h1>
    holaaaaaaaa
   </div>
   
   <div style="height:100vh">
    <h1>Hello, world 3</h1>
    holaaaaaaaa
   </div>
   <div style="height:100vh">
    <h1>Hello, world 4</h1>
    holaaaaaaaa
   </div>
   <div style="height:100vh">
    <h1>Hello, world 5</h1>
    holaaaaaaaa
   </div>
   <div style="height:100vh">
    <h1>Hello, world 6</h1>
    holaaaaaaaa
   </div>
   <div class="opera" style="height:100vh">
    <h1>Hello, world 7</h1>
    holaaaaaaaa
   </div>
   
  </div> 
  </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: puedes explicar cual es tu error? no es suficiente con una imagen, no sabemos que quieres solucionar.

Comment: hola,si claro, mira la imagen que coloque muestra como el div <div id="triangle" class=" div-cut top">jofret</div>  se sale del viewport, es el que hace un efecto de linea diagnal

Comment: aun sigues con el problema?

Comment: Hola que tal, sorry no te pude contestar, justo antes fallo el ventilador de mi laptop y recién hace un rato salí de ese stress, lo pude solucionar :)!!. Si me funciono cien puntos. Gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analizando lo que me dices, logro entender de que esta seria una solucion para tu problema, lo que hice fue agregar al `body` `margin: 0;` y cambiar el atributo `left` de la clase `.div-cut` por `right`, espero que te funcione.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
h1{margin:0}
    
.div-cut.top {
    top: 0;
    border-top: 250px solid #fff;
    border-right: 100vw solid red;
}
.div-cut {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
}

.absolut{position:absolute;}
.fix{position:fixed}

.EstilosParaFondo{
    z-index:10; 
    top:0; top:0; left:0; right:0; 
    margin:auto;  
    background-image:url('images/imagenOK.jpg'); 
    background-size:cover; 
    background-repeat:no-repeat; 
    height: 450px; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    

    <div style="background:white; height:80vh; width:100%">
    <h1>Hello, world 1</h1>
  </div> 
  
  <div id="div2" style="position:relative; background-color:#FF4D4D;">
  
    <div id="triangle" class=" div-cut top">jofret</div>
    
    <div>

            <div style="height:100vh">
                <h1>Hello, world 2</h1>
                holaaaaaaaa
            </div>
            
            <div style="height:100vh">
                <h1>Hello, world 3</h1>
                holaaaaaaaa
            </div>
            <div style="height:100vh">
                <h1>Hello, world 4</h1>
                holaaaaaaaa
            </div>
            <div style="height:100vh">
                <h1>Hello, world 5</h1>
                holaaaaaaaa
            </div>
            <div style="height:100vh">
                <h1>Hello, world 6</h1>
                holaaaaaaaa
            </div>
            <div class="opera" style="height:100vh">
                <h1>Hello, world 7</h1>
                holaaaaaaaa
            </div>
            
        </div>  
  </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```